# BorderPane overlaping content

Tags: java, javafx

I have child GridPane, I want if text will increase then text should
not goes to out of gridPane, instead ScrollPane, I don't want see go Apple text out side of box.

```
  @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    String border = "-fx-border-color:red;";

    Text title=new Text("Machin");

    GridPane topLeft=new GridPane();
    topLeft.setMinSize(80, 5);
    topLeft.setMaxSize(80, 80);

    topLeft.setStyle(border);

    topLeft.add(title, 0, 0);

    for(int i=1;i<=15;i++) {
        topLeft.add(new Text("Apple"), 0,i);
    }


    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    root.setHgap(20);
    root.setVgap(20);

    root.add(topLeft, 0, 0);



    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setTop(new Label("Header"));
    borderPane.setCenter(root);
    borderPane.setBottom(new Label("Buttom"));


    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: You might consider `ListView` over `GridPane`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a layout pane like a [GridPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), you can use some of the more sophisticated controls like [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm) or [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm) to enclose your content.  Those controls have in-built scrollbars which will show when the content of the controls is larger than the viewable area.  Review the linked tutorials to assess whether those other controls are applicable for your application.

If you wish to keep with a `GridPane`, then you can wrap the `GridPane` in a [ScrollPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) to allow the content of the `GridPane` to be scrolled if it reaches a certain size, such as in the sample below:

[image: scrollable grid]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollingGrid extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String border = "-fx-border-color:red;";
        Text title = new Text("Machin");

        GridPane appleGrid = new GridPane();
        appleGrid.setMinSize(80, 5);
        appleGrid.setStyle(border);
        appleGrid.add(title, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            appleGrid.add(new Text("Apple"), 0, i);
        }

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(appleGrid);
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(80);
        scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(80);
        scrollPane.setMaxSize(ScrollPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, ScrollPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(new Label("Header"));
        borderPane.setCenter(scrollPane);
        borderPane.setBottom(new Label("Bottom"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```